# Estimate duplet probability of patients

Tags: probability, estimation

I would like to estimate the probability that two patients in a system have the same first and last name and birthdate.

This is not easy as names are not distributed evenly and I don't know the number of names around. So I thought to estimate a worst case scenario like follows and would like to know if this makes sense:

The last name Müller (German) is most common name with 1.6%.
The firstname Marie (also German) is currently the most common with 2.6%.
As Birthdates are not distributed evenly across a Year I estimate 1/300 probability for the average birthdate

Now I just multiplied those three to get an estimate of the case that the most common scenario has a duplet. Does this make sense?

Comment: As far as I remember the year consists of approximately 365 days.  But I did not check for a long time.

Comment: I estimated 300 to compensate the effect that birthdates are not distributed evenly. I also mentioned that above. Otherwise I would have used 365.25.

Comment: It seems to be a rather voluntary assumption. I see at the moment no justification for it.

Comment: Are you looking for the probability that two randomly chosen people have identical data or that there is at least one pair of people in the data base which have identical data or that there is at least  one pair of people in the data base which have the **given** identical data? In the two latter cases the probability obviously depends on the size of the data base.

Comment: This question arose in the context how safe it is, to assign laboratory results to patients fules based on firstname, lastname and birthdate. I am currently discussing that with customers and vota against a fully automated mechanism due to the result I estimated for the worst case scenario. Sure, it deoends on the size of the database. As not all patients for which results are received are in the database, it is not possible to check for duplets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_i,l_j,b_k$ be the probabilities to have $i$-th first name, $j$-th last name, and $k$-th birthday. Then the probability that the data base contains two people with three given characteristics is:
$$
(f_il_jb_k)^2,
$$
and the probability that there are at least two people with identical three characteristics is:
$$\sum_{i,j,k}(f_il_jb_k)^2.
$$

It was assumed that all three characteristics are independent, though in reality the first name and the birthday can heavily correlate.